# How I can add N time item using n2cms

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, n2cms, n2

I am new in N2 CMS and i am stuck in dynamic content like add n time item.
This is an example
This object consists of:

```
        WYSIWYG / Richtext Editor (This will be [EditableFreeTextAreaAttribute])
        **n-times item**
           caption  [EditableText]
           image  [FileAttachment]
```

My question is, How I can make it N times where i have 1 RTE and n time Caption and image. Currently i am stuck on it. Please suggest me how I can comeup with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the EditableChildren attribute.  Basically you define a content item for the child item - eg. image and caption.

Then your main ContentItem has a rich text editor and a collection of the child content item.

Example:

```
namespace N2.Templates.Items
{

 [PageDefinition("FAQ", 
        Description = "A list of frequently asked questions with answers.",
        SortOrder = 200,
        IconUrl = "~/Templates/UI/Img/help.png")]
    [AvailableZone("Questions", "Questions")]
    [RestrictParents(typeof(IStructuralPage))]
    [ConventionTemplate]
    public class FaqList : AbstractContentPage, IStructuralPage
    {
        [N2.Details.EditableChildren("Questions", "Questions", 110, ContainerName=Tabs.Content)]
        public virtual IList<Faq> Questions
        {
            get { return GetChildren<Faq>("Questions"); }
        }
    }
}
```

https://github.com/n2cms/n2cms/blob/6b8698468b61cff0ee1825644b05b63d011bf7e8/src/WebForms/WebFormsTemplates/Templates/Items/FaqList.cs